# Executing multiple python commands in linux

Tags: python, linux, command-line, batch-processing, execution

I have multiple commands in a file in the following format

```
    python dosomething.py arg1 arg2
    python dosomethingelse.py arg1 arg2
```

I want to execute one by one.

What is the elegant way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: people what is going on, if its a duplicate, mention it and could be closed, but why the negative vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have those lines in a file (say, `run-python-scripts.sh`), you can run it with `sh`:

```
sh run-python-scripts.sh
```